# Repeated page element and django

Tags: django

I have a repeated page element that may go in different pages or within the same page, such as a signature of the user, and I want to prevent repeating the same HTML again and again. One option I have is to define a user-defined filter, and pipe the data into the filter, or a custom tag. I don't know if it's a good idea to keep the HTML in a filter, in terms of layer responsibility. What's the preferred way of doing so in django?

Answer (score 4):

If it's HTML that doesn't need to to anything clever, use the [include](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#include) tag to pull in the repeated partial template from a single file. You can reference variables from the containing template in that include.

If you need to perform operations on data so that the template partial may render different values based on different circumstances, but with the same HTML layout, write an [inclusion tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#howto-custom-template-tags-inclusion-tags)